# How camera flash can send information

Tags: visible-light, infrared-radiation, camera

Nikon have CLS a system that allow to trigger one flash with other flash. I don't know how exactly it work from user point of view, I think that one flash (in command mode) can send information like flash compensation (+ or -) or metering using TTL (I think that when that option is turn on light meter from camera change how external flash function). How this is possible from physics point of view? How flash which is just light can send information? I know that you can send information with fiber optics but I don't think that this is the same.

Comment: It uses [infrared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared) light. It's just like Wi-Fi, TV, radio communications, etc. Btw, migrate to [Photo.SE](photo.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @jcubic: "How flash which is just light can send information?" Radios, TV's, wireless internet ports, and submarines all communicate with various forms of light. Why do you think it's not possible to communicate with light? Light is being used all around you every day to communicate. The letters you typed on your keyboard to write this question were probably transmitted with light.

Comment: @jinawee I didn't want to put it to photo.stackexchange.com, because I wanted to know the answer from physics point of view, not photography.

Comment: @jinawee can the owner migrate the question? I thought only moderator can do this, and other people can only flag a question.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus What I read here: http://www.scantips.com/lights/awl.html is that the master flash uses IR light to control the other flashes  (just like a TV remote control), not visible light. It would be better if the OP explained Nikon's technology.

Comment: @jinawee I didn't know how this work, so your comment just answer my question. You can create an answer with just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read here: http://scantips.com/lights/awl.html, the master flash uses [IRlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared)  to control the other flashes (just like a TV remote control), not visible light.

[image]

*(The red thing is the IR sensor)*

Anyway, light can transmit information just as any electromagnetic wave. Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to see the objects around you! There would be some problems with visible light due to interferences between the light from the emmiter and the ambient light.

Comment: As a curiosity, you can "see" infrared light using a mobile phone camera.

Answer (score 1):

From http://pixsylated.com/blog/canon-speedlite-optical-wireless-fundamentals/ :

> With optical wireless, the master sends instructions to the slave(s)
>   via a series of pre-flashes that come just before the main flash.
>   These instructions tell the slave what mode to use (ETTL, Manual, or
>   Multi), what power to fire at, and what sync speed to use.
>
> When you make a change to the settings on the master, the instructions
>   will be sent to the slaves when the master next fires.
>
> The slaves will change their settings instantaneously and fire when
>   the master tells them to fire. Once a Speedlite is set-up as a slave
>   (which will be covered in part three), you change the slave’s
>   operation via the master Speedlite. Remember, you won’t see a change
>   on the slave’s settings until the master fires—an expectation that
>   drives many novice Speedliters crazy.

This makes sense. The flash is very powerful - and just by controlling the spacing between a series of short flashes you can communicate many things.

**A simpler time**
I used to have a TTL flash years ago (Minolta) that had a "on and off" master/slave trick: it would notice when the main flash (built into the camera) would turn on, and it would notice again when the main flash turned off. So the order of events was:

1. You press the shutter
2. shutter opens, built in flash triggers
3. slave notices flash of light, turns on
4. camera measures light received through the lens (in the days of film, this was with a sensor that "looked at" the emulsion on the film
5. when enough light was received, it turned off the internal flash. Doing so would actually generate a short bright "spike"
6. the slave flash notices the spike and turns off
7. the shutter closes

Not quite as sophisticated as modern techniques but quite effective.

Answer (score 0):

> How flash which is just light can send information? I know that you can send information with fiber optics but I don't think that this is the same.

I think it is (more or less) the same. Maybe this question is no so much physics as it is information theory or telecommunication. Very much simplified: most telecommunication uses a carrier wave and an envelope. The carrier wave in this case could be the visible light, which of course is not so much a carrier wavelength, but more a set of wavelengths somewhere between $4 \times 10^{14} $ Hz and $4 \times 10^{14} $ Hz, or 400 to 800 THz. The carrier wave can fluctuate in modulation. The envelope is a (smooth) wave that contains this carrier wave that changes in amplitude. Depending on what modulation technique you use, you can send information in a speed that is a fraction of the carrier wave. The information you want to actually send is just in the order of bytes, so I think the flash needed to actually send all the information required is so fast you'd probably not even notice it. On top of that, the communication flash is followed by a (probably much brighter and much longer) flash, so even if you would be able to see it under normal circumstances, the communication-light would fade in comparison.

To show an example on how light can be used to communicate data, you could take a look at [LiFi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li-Fi), a technique to transmit data using visible light.

> Li-Fi uses the modulation of light intensity to transmit data. Li-Fi can theoretically transmit at speeds of up to 100 Gbit/s.